# Include spark avoiding huge dependencies

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I would like to include spark sql in my project. However, if doing so, the jar file becomes huge (over 120 MB) because Maven includes numerous dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to minimize the included dependencies?

Comment: Basic question: why you want to embed Spark in other application? It should run on a cluster, not embedded in other application

Comment: I am not really interested in Spark. But I need some kind of data frame like R data frame or Pandas data frame in Java and the code must be under an Apache or MIT license. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: For what kind of work you want to have dataframes?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your use case. By default, maven includes all the dependencies of spark-sql in the uber jar. Based on your case, you may not use all of them. So you can exclude them from your dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- to remove jackson-databind from your uber jar -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusions>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But this won't help you if your application uses most of the features of spark-sql.

In many of the cases, the spark dependencies will be provided by the environment in which you are going to run your application(apart from standalone mode). In such cases, you can just flag spark-sql dependency as provided dependency as shown below,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```